# Find the largest domain where $z-z^2+z^3...$ has

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=z-z^2+z^3...$, $|z|<1$. Find the largest domain where $f$ can be extend analytically.

The radius of convergence of $f$ is obviously $1$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$ \frac1{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots
$$
for $|x| < 1$.

Comment: I guess $f(z)=-\frac{1}{1+z}+1$ on $|z|<1$. Therefore $f(z)$ can be extended analytically to $\mathbb C\setminus\{-1\}$?